# Mostrar solo elementos repetidos con Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Supongamos que tengo listado en *.csv* con diferentes columnas, una de ellas es "nombre profesor", la segunda "asignatura" y la tercera es "año".

Pudiendo quedar algo similar a esto:

```
Nombre profesor  Asignatura  Año
Juan             Mates       2002
Pedro            Lengua      2003
Luisa            Mates       2005
Natalia          Inglés      2002
Juan             Inglés      2008
Natalia          Física      2004
Juan             Inglés      2018
Luisa            Mates       2018
```

**EDITO PREGUNTA** 
¿Hay alguna manera de mostrar mediante comandos de `pandas` solo aquellos profesores que hacen más de una asignatura **diferente**? Es decir que quedase algo así:

```
Nombre profesor  Count     
Juan             2     
Natalia          2
```

Ya que Juan sale 3 veces pero dos veces su asignatura es la misma, inglés y al igual le pasa lo mismo a Luisa, que sale dos veces pero la asignatura es la misma, mates, por lo tanto no cuenta.

Se me ocurre emplear `groupby()`

```
datos = pd.read_csv('fichero.csv')
p = datos.groupby('Nombre_profesor','Asignatura').size().loc[lambda x: x>1]
```

Pero si no me equivoco esto muestra aquellos profesores que se repiten y que hacen una misma asignatura. Es decir, justo los que yo quiero descartar por lo tanto no tengo claro que hacer.

¡¡Gracias!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero reproducimos tu ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

txt = """
Nombre_profesor  Asignatura  Año
Juan             Mates       2002
Pedro            Lengua      2003
Luisa            Mates       2005
Luisa            Mates       2006
Natalia          Inglés      2002
Juan             Inglés      2008
Natalia          Física      2004"""
 
datos = pd.read_table(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+")
```

Lo que buscas es obtener los profesores que tienen más de una materia distinta. Modifiqué tu ejemplo, para ver un caso de un profesor con la misma materia en dos años distintos (debería contar 1).

Para obtener un `dataframe` con las cantidades de materias distintas por profesor, podemos hacer:

```
p = datos.groupby('Nombre_profesor').Asignatura.nunique().reset_index()
print(p)

  Nombre_profesor  Asignatura
0            Juan           2
1           Luisa           1
2         Natalia           2
3           Pedro           1
```

Fijate que `Luisa` tiene la misma materia en dos años diferentes y aún así la cuenta nos da 1. Lo siguiente es filtrar aquellos casos dónde esta cantidad es mayor a 1:

```
print(p.loc[p['Asignatura'] > 1])

  Nombre_profesor  Asignatura
0            Juan           2
2         Natalia           2
```

#### Explicación:

- Con `datos` hacemos un agrupamiento por `Nombre_profesor` mediante [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby)
- De cada grupo usando `Asignatura.nunique()` contamos las asignaturas distintas. Con `reset_index()` dejamos `Asignatura` como una columna más
- Por último `p.loc[p['Asignatura'] > 1]` filtramos únicamente aquellos casos que tuvieran más de una asignatura

Comment: Pero realmente aquí estás mirando los profesores que aparecen más de una vez y yo querría mostrar en la tabla final los profesores pero mirarlo desde las asignaturas. Ya se que se que para este ejemplo desde los profesores se llega a lo mismo pero quiero aprender a hacerlo desde el otro campo. Aún así muchas gracias, este ejemplo ya me lo he guardado!

Comment: he hecho `p = datos.groupby('Nombre_profesor','Asignatura').size().loc[lambda x: x>1]` pero no sé si es correcto.

Comment: Hola NEA, francamente no entiendo a que te refieres, la salida final es exactamente igual al ejemplo que indicaste, tal vez puedas reformular tu pregunta y con gusto trataré de ayudarte.

Comment: Reformulé la pregunta, muchas gracias

Comment: @NEA, revisa mi última edición, entiendo que lo que buscas es contar materias "distintas" por profesor, cualquier cosa me dices...